# ElasticSearch don't return the expected results when column row has _ (underline)

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch in my app to search products by SKU. In some cases the code of SKU can has underline/underscore like this examples: 27_58, 48_12, 27_99

To find in ElasticSearch I'm using the package `plastic` by `sleimanx2` (https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic)

The problem is that if I search for `27`, the ElasticSearch don't return the expected results.

The code I'm using is this:

```
 $q_search = Sku::search()->must()->match('sku', '27')->size(10000); 
 $q_result = $q_search->get()->hits();
```

The ElasticSearch don't return the two SKUs expecteds (27_58, 27_99)

Does anyone know what the problem is? Is there any special character like `_` in ElasticSearch?